# How do i use comprehensions to output dictionary data after editing it and how to validate user input asking user to repeat

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
eList = []

while True:

    eDict = {
        "ID": "",
        "NAME": "",
        "EMAIL": "",
        "ADDRESS": "",
        "SALARY": ""}
    try:
        eId = int(input("Enter Employee ID: "))
        if len(str(eId)) <= 7:
            pass
        else:
            print("ID should be of length less than or equal to 7")
    except ValueError:
        print(" ")

    try:
        eName = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
        if len(eName) > 2:
            eDict["NAME"] = eName
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
    except:
        print("zvatoramba ka")
        continue

    try:
        eEmail = input("Enter Employee Email: ")
        if len(eEmail) > 2:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
    except:
        print("zvatoramba ka")
        continue

    try:
        eAddress = input("Enter Employee Address: ")
        if len(eAddress) > 2:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
    except:
        print("zvatoramba ka")
        continue

    try:
        eSalary = float(input("Enter Employee Salary: "))
        if 18 < eSalary > 27:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
    except:
        print("zvatoramba ka")
        continue

    eDict["ID"] = eId
    eDict["NAME"] = eName
    eDict["EMAIL"] = eEmail
    eDict["ADDRESS"] = eAddress
    eDict["SALARY"] = eSalary
    eList.append(eDict)

    if input("Do you want to continue? [y/n]: ") != "y":
        break



eList[eDict["SALARY"]] = eSalary*1.3
eDict.update({"NAME": eName + " IT Department"})

print(eList)
```

This is a list of dictionaries and here i am trying to change each NAME after compiling all the data. With the try and except im trying to validate user information and make it tell the user to repeat again when they enter wrong information. Im not getting it right.

Comment: When using fenced code blocks you need to use _backticks_ (`\``) (or tildes—`~`), not double (`"`) or single quotes (`'`)

Comment: A couple of points: (1) You only need `try`-`except` when you are trying to convert the input string into `int`/`float` - in all other cases there will be no exception, whatever your input looks like. (2) I guess you want the `continue` also in the `else`-parts of the `if`-`else`-blocks? (3) `18 < eSalary > 27` is strange - do you mean `18 < eSalary < 27`? (4) The code after the input block looks rather strange?

Answer (score 0):

As @timus mentioned above, there should be a `continue` statement for all the `else` parts. You can also raise an exception from else since all the exceptions have continue block. You need to loop through `eList` in order to update all the names.

I think the below code should do the trick.

```
eList = []

while True:

    eDict = {
        "ID": "",
        "NAME": "",
        "EMAIL": "",
        "ADDRESS": "",
        "SALARY": ""}

    try:
        eId = int(input("Enter Employee ID: "))
        if len(str(eId)) <= 7:
            pass
        else:
            print("ID should be of length less than or equal to 7")
            raise ValueError

        eName = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
        if len(eName) > 2:
            eDict["NAME"] = eName
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
            raise Exception

        eEmail = input("Enter Employee Email: ")
        if len(eEmail) > 2:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
            raise Exception

        eAddress = input("Enter Employee Address: ")
        if len(eAddress) > 2:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
            raise Exception

        eSalary = float(input("Enter Employee Salary: "))
        if 18 < eSalary > 27:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("Length haiskuita wangu")
            raise Exception

    except ValueError:
        print(" ")
        continue

    except:
        print("zvatoramba ka")
        continue

    eDict["ID"] = eId
    eDict["NAME"] = eName
    eDict["EMAIL"] = eEmail
    eDict["ADDRESS"] = eAddress
    eDict["SALARY"] = eSalary
    eList.append(eDict)

    if input("Do you want to continue? [y/n]: ") != "y":
        break


for edict in eList:
    edict["SALARY"] *= 1.3
    edict.update({"NAME": edict["NAME"] + " IT Department"})

print(eList)
```